# Error while initializing MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, initialization

I'm trying to initialize MongoDB from a tutorial and I had to write the following code:

`mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo.db --logappend --install`

After I type it, it gives me the following error:

```
2018-02-27T21:11:20.978-0800 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "C:\mongodb\log\mongo.db"
```

I don't have the directory "log" but nor does the guy in the tutorial, so I'm a little confused what might be the problem.

Comment: try this mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongodb.log --logappend --install

Comment: it still gives me the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have the files "log" and "data", and inside of data the file "db". You have to create those files manually in order for it to work.